# How to make Microsoft Storage Explorer calculate ContentMD5

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using MS Storage Explorer (version 1.7) to upload files to a blob container in my Azure storage account.  As a test, I made two copies of a file, uploaded one as a block blob and one as an append blob.

Afterward, I checked properties on each file; the one I uploaded as block had the ContentMD5 property set, but the one I uploaded as append did not have the property set.

Is this expected behavior?  I would like to have ContentMD5 automatically set, so I don't have to calculate it and set it myself.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `ContentMD5` is calculated at client side, it's a good idea to calculate and set the property for block blob, since block blob content is fixed after calling `PutBlockList`.

However, it's inappropriate to set the property for append blob, since append blob content can be altered after being appended. After that, `ContentMD5` set previously will become incorrect. Further more, append blob can be appended by multiple clients simultaneously, which means the value calculated from one client is not reliable at all.